# Print matching String, of list of Strings, for each filename

Tags: python, string

I am using Os.Walk to get all filenames, now I want to see if each filenames has certain string in them.

If they do I would like to print does matching words.

I am aware that my current code won't do that.
This is part of a larger code, which should give a dic, with bunches of info about the files in the end. But I can't write down the filenames, so I need to see if these words exist, through my code.

What I have:

```
import os

match = ["draft", "first", "test"]

for filenames in os.walk("C:\\Users\"):
    if filenames is like match:
        print(#what_matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the strings in the list are inside the file, then you need first read the files.

Comment: I want to look at the filenames.

Comment: In that case, I think you could solve the problem by creating a nested for loop.